# R Shiny: Allow download of a plot image through browser with file name

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a shiny app that renders a plot using ggplot2. In fact, the browser's download image button works too (right click). And, when I download the image it does and displays when I open the file.

Only problem is that the file name to which it downloads is simply called 'untitled'. I want to make the file download to a name. But, I don't want to use the 'download image/plot' button. All examples I see show this option. Want to use built-in browser capability.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you're just re-saving the displayed image, rather than exporting the plot with ggsave, you should just change the file name when saving it. Enable your browser's "Ask where to save each file before downloading", or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a button, you could use ggsave inside the function that creates the plot: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/ggsave.html